# Python webscraping : BeautifulSoup, not getting full data, and how to loop to update data

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

i'm new to coding just started to learn Python, my code is about scraping currency data (name and price), once i get all the names and prices i'll select one currency to display it's value, then enter an "Alert" value to compare it with the "price" once the price = Alert value i print something or get notification.

i'm getting both (name and price) name is ok, but i'm not getting the full "price" data, in website price = 6.74194772 and the data i'm getting is 6.74, i have 2 questions:

1. could you please explain what's wrong with my code and how to fixe it.
2. how do i loop to update the price and keep comparing it to the Alert price.

website code : Ps: i changed the name of currency to "Currency name"

```
<tr class = "tv-data-table__row tv-data-table__stroke tv-screener-table__result-row"
data - symbol = "BITSTAMP:BTCUSD" >
    <td class = "tv-data-table__cell tv-screener-table__cell tv-screener-table__cell--left tv-screener-table__cell--big"
title = "100" >
    <div class = "tv-screener-table__symbol-container" >
    <img alt = ""class = "tv-circle-logo tv-circle-logo--medium tv-screener-table__logo-container"
src = "https://s3-symbol-logo.tradingview.com/crypto/XTVCBTC.svg" / >
    <div >
    <a class = "tv-screener__symbol"
href = "/markets/cryptocurrencies/prices-cryptoxtvcbtc/"
target = "_blank" > Currency_name < /a> </div >
    </div> </td> <td class = "tv-data-table__cell tv-screener-table__cell tv-screener-table__cell--big" > 718.269 B  
         </td><td class="tv-data-table__cell tv-screener-table__cell tv-screener-table__cell--big">803.380B
         </td > <td class = "tv-data-table__cell tv-screener-table__cell tv-screener-table__cell--big" > Title data-field-key="close"> <span>6.74194772<span> 
         </td><td class="tv-data-table__cell tv-screener-table__cell tv-screener-table__cell--big">18.775M
         </td ><td class = "tv-data-table__cell tv-screener-table__cell tv-screener-table__cell--big" > 21.000 M 
         </td><td class="tv-data-table__cell tv-screener-table__cell tv-screener-table__cell--big">26.314B
         </td > <td class = "tv-data-table__cell tv-screener-table__cell tv-screener-table__cell--big tv-screener-table__cell--down" > -2.32 % < /td> </tr >
```

this is some of my code :

```
 from typing import Container, Text
from urllib.request import urlopen as req
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup



my_url = 'https://fr.tradingview.com/markets/cryptocurrencies/prices-all/'
uclient = req(my_url)
p_price = uclient.read()
uclient.close()
myop = soup(p_price, "lxml.parser")
containers = myop.findAll("tr", {"class":"tv-data-table__row tv-data-table__stroke tv-screener-table__result-row"})

def scrape():
    for container in containers:
        name_container = container.findAll("a", {"class":"tv-screener__symbol"})
        name = name_container[0].text
        title_container = container.findAll("td", {"class":"tv-data-table__cell tv-screener-table__cell tv-screener-table__cell--big"})
        price = title_container[2].text
    # print(str(name)  + " : "  + price)
        
        Dictionary[name] = price
#print(Dictionary)
scrape()
Crypto_name = input("Enter Crypro name : ")    #enter currency name
Valp = Dictionary[Crypto_name]                 #get price data for specific currency
print(Crypto_name + " = " + Valp)              #print currency and price
Alert_st = input("Enter your target price : ") #enter Alert price

while Valp != Alert_st:
  if Valp == Alert_st:                         #compare price and Alert price
    print("Alert price !")             
  else:
    print(Valp)                                #should print UPDATED price 
         
  scrape()
```

problem is that the price is repeating, it's the same not updating.

Comment: I don't see where you are making the request to the site. It's possible that the price repeats because you just keep parsing the same/original html. Secondly, when do the numbers change?

Comment: i just updated the code, that's the full code

Comment: As I suspected. You only request 1 time, and just parse that same html. If you want to check for it to update, you need to make a new request and check, which is what my code does.

Comment: guys help please ...

Answer (score 0):

Could you post more of your code? It's not clear to me what URL you're scraping from.

This goes beyond your scraping question but an API might be more reliable to use in this instance.
(free APIs: https://api.coinpaprika.com and https://www.coingecko.com/en/api)

Comment: that's the important part of code the rest is importing lib and usual stuff... i'll make a second code using API, the current code is teaching me a lot.
Url i used : https://fr.tradingview.com/markets/cryptocurrencies/prices-all/

Comment: Try opening the URL with view-source like so:
view-source:https://fr.tradingview.com/markets/cryptocurrencies/prices-all/

What you will see is that your script is working correctly, however the prices you see on the page when you visit it without view-source are changed through Javascript after the page is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a request each time to check if the number changed. I put a little time delay, so it'll check every 30 seconds:

```
import pandas as pd
import time

url = 'https://fr.tradingview.com/markets/cryptocurrencies/prices-all/'

def scrape():
    # reads the html and parses the <table> tags. 
    #It will return as a list of dataframes and we want the dataframe in index position 0
    df = pd.read_html(url)[0]
    
    # Filtering/slicing the data frame- We want every row `:`, 
    # and the 1st and 4th columns represented by indices 0 and 3
    df = df.iloc[:,[0,3]]
    return df
    
#print(Dictionary)
orginal_df = scrape()
Crypto_name = input("Enter Crypro name : ")    #enter currency name

# We filter the dataframe from the function above
# This will get the rows where the 1st column (at index 0), matches the Crypto_name enterd
# Then it will get the row (index 0) and the 2nd column (index 1) which the price value
Valp = orginal_df[orginal_df.iloc[:,0] == Crypto_name].loc[0][1]               #get price data for specific currency
print(Crypto_name + " = " + str(Valp))              #print currency and price
Alert_st = float(input("Enter your target price : ")) #enter Alert price

while Valp != Alert_st:
    orginal_df = scrape()
    
    # Same slicing as mentioned above, but obviously checking the updated/new request to the site 
    Valp = orginal_df[orginal_df.iloc[:,0] == Crypto_name].loc[0][1]   
    if Valp == Alert_st:                         #compare price and Alert price
        print("Alert price !")             
    else:
        print(Valp)     
    time.sleep(30)
```

**Using beautfulsoup:**

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as req
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import time


my_url = 'https://fr.tradingview.com/markets/cryptocurrencies/prices-all/'

def scrape():
    dictionary = {}
    uclient = req(my_url)
    p_price = uclient.read()
    uclient.close()
    myop = soup(p_price, "html.parser")
    containers = myop.findAll("tr", {"class":"tv-data-table__row tv-data-table__stroke tv-screener-table__result-row"})
    for container in containers:
        name_container = container.findAll("a", {"class":"tv-screener__symbol"})
        name = name_container[0].text
        title_container = container.findAll("td", {"class":"tv-data-table__cell tv-screener-table__cell tv-screener-table__cell--big"})
        price = title_container[2].text
        
        dictionary[name] = float(price)
    
    return dictionary
        

#print(Dictionary)
dictionary = scrape()
Crypto_name = input("Enter Crypro name : ")    #enter currency name
Valp = dictionary[Crypto_name]                 #get price data for specific currency
print(Crypto_name + " = " + str(Valp))              #print currency and price
Alert_st = float(input("Enter your target price : ")) #enter Alert price

while Valp != Alert_st:
    dictionary = scrape()
    Valp = dictionary[Crypto_name]     
    if Valp == Alert_st:                         #compare price and Alert price
        print("Alert price !")             
    else:
        print(Valp)

    time.sleep(30)                                  #should print UPDATED price
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, since i started Python few days ago, i didn't understand what you added could you please explain what each part does, thank you.
Ps: i've posted the full code

Comment: Ok thank you so much, i used "Beautifulsoup" not "panda" (i know nothing about panda yet ) could you please use/fix my code.

Comment: you forgot about me

Comment: I did not forget, but SO is not a python tutorial service. If you're just starting off with python, then I'd suggest do an actual online tutorial/class to learn the basics, rather than jump right into something more complex like web scraping. I updated my code to use beautifulsoup.

Comment: i am learning, otherwise i wouldn't writ my code, i did not ask for a tutorial, i asked for help just like any beginner, and ppl are free to answer and help or not, everyone who post or change a code should add comments i's a common practice it's not a tutorial .... you did not add comment, no worries i'll find help.

Comment: I added the comments in. The comments are basic and can be found in the pandas documentation. I will reiterate my statement, that being new to python and jumping straight into web scraping is difficult if you don't have the basics including data slicing, pandas (pandas is a highly used and useful package to know). So find a tutorial that will cover those basics, particularly pandas.Heres a good one at [datacamp](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/pandas-tutorial-dataframe-python). With that being said, web scraping is particularly fun! So I get why you're doing it and happy learning!

Comment: thank you sir, i may be wrong learning "BeautifulSoup" before "Panda" i will take your advice and try to do both, yes web scraping is fun but i'm doing this project as motivation, it will motivate me even more if i do it, i always set the bar high to motivate myself (i may be wrong). Thank you for everything.

Comment: Pandas does use beautifulsoup under the hood. essentially pd.read_html(), is driven by soup.find_all('table'), etc etc. So in some ways, learning beautifulsoup here will help you understand the .read_html() function.

Comment: ok thanks,
i have a question please,  the url i was using (main page) got a list of all currencies and it's taking 7 minutes to update and it's not accurate, so i changed the Url (to this https://www.tradingview.com/markets/cryptocurrencies/prices-xrp/) to 1 specific currency to scrape it since it's faster than the main page . Now i'm able to get the name but not the price  at  <div class="tv-symbol-price-quote__value js-symbol-last"> 
  any idea why ?